# ScrollView Is Not Moving Correctly with Next and Previous Button tapped in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollviewdelegate

```
-(IBAction)nextButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (moreItemsgridView.contentOffset.x<=moreItemsgridView.contentSize.width) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = moreItemsgridView.contentOffset.x + moreItemsgridView.frame.size.width;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size  = moreItemsgridView.frame.size;
        [moreItemsgridView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
        //[moreItemsgridView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(moreItemsgridView.contentOffset.x + moreItemsgridView.contentSize.width, 0) animated:NO];
    }
}

-(IBAction)previousButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (moreItemsgridView.contentOffset.x>=moreItemsgridView.frame.size.width) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = moreItemsgridView.contentOffset.x - moreItemsgridView.frame.size.width;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = moreItemsgridView.frame.size;
        [moreItemsgridView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
    }
}
```

My image Scrolls Correctly When I tapped NEXT BUTTON but When I Click Previous Button it scrolls correctly but at the end it showing only half of the view...What I am doing wrong...Please Help me with this....

Comment: Do you have `pagingEnabled` set on your scroll view? If not, are you allowing the user to scroll part of the way, so your "grid" is not aligned? And, if so, on button tap are you trying to scroll to a "grid" position, or just scroll a "width" distance?

Answer (score -1):

Call  `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` after you update the frame.

```
-(IBAction)nextButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (moreItemsgridView.contentOffset.x<=moreItemsgridView.contentSize.width) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = moreItemsgridView.contentOffset.x + moreItemsgridView.frame.size.width;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size  = moreItemsgridView.frame.size;
        [moreItemsgridView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
        //[moreItemsgridView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(moreItemsgridView.contentOffset.x + moreItemsgridView.contentSize.width, 0) animated:NO];


 [self.view layoutIfNeeded]

    }
}

-(IBAction)previousButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (moreItemsgridView.contentOffset.x>=moreItemsgridView.frame.size.width) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = moreItemsgridView.contentOffset.x - moreItemsgridView.frame.size.width;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = moreItemsgridView.frame.size;
        [moreItemsgridView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];


        [self.view layoutIfNeeded]
    }
}
```

Comment: Where Exactly @Vinay Kiran

Comment: [moreItemsgridView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];  You mean by here